# Eclipse API: Deleting an IJavaProject

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

How do I delete an existing IJavaProject?

I tried looking at `IJavaModel.delete(..)`, but it only deletes IJavaElements. Is it enough to simply delete the IJavaProject's IProject?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can delete the underlying IProject and that will delete the IJavaProject.  This is because the JDT stores all of the extra info that makes an IJavaProject an IJavaProject inside the underlying IProject.